# Trying to turn 2 columns into one using @media

Tags: html, css

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I'm trying to turn these two columns into 1 when viewing the site on a mobile phone.

```css
html {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#nav-bar {
  background-color: #A1CCD1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

h2 {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

img {
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  border: 3px solid darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: #A1CCD1;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.first {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.motor {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

@media (max-width=768px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Resume</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <a href="./index.html">Resume</a>
    <a href="./hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
    <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <h1 class="first">Hobbies</h1>
    <div class="motor">
      <h2>Motorsports</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/gti.JPG" alt="Picture of my MK7 Gti.">
      <p>
        I am a huge fan of Motorsports. I watch F1, Formula Drift, and a lot of different e-sport racing events. I have a pretty decent racing sim, which I use to play sims such as iRacing, Assetto Corsa and Assetto Corsa Competizione. I'm pretty passionate about
        working on my own cars as well. I currently own a MK7 GTi making over 400 HP with plans to take her to the track soon. Follow the car account on <a href="https://instagram.com/mk7_unbound">instagram</a> if you're interested!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Multicopters</h2>
      <p>
        A hobby I haven't been able to fully dive into yet due to the high expenses of my Motorsports hobby, but I am able to deeply enjoy flying my DJI around. This hobby pairs nicely with Motorsports to get those nice rolling or action shots. There's something
        really satisfying about flying up into the air and seeing the world from a different perspective. After saving up a little bit more money I plan on buying a full FPV setup for maximum immersion.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Video games</h2>
      <p>
        Of course playing video games is one of my major hobbies. My top games include:
        <ol>
          <li>Diablo 4</li>
          <li>Escape From Tarkov</li>
          <li>Valorant</li>
          <li>Rocket League</li>
          <li>Final Fantasy XIV</li>
        </ol>
        Gaming has been in my blood ever since I was 7 years old playing on the NES and it's something I can see myself doing for the long term. The variety of games you can play now is astounding and technological advances just keep pushing the limits of what
        we can do. It's all very exciting and I cannot wait to see where the industry ends up in 15 years.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried doing

```
@media (max-width = 768px) {
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr
    }
```

While also removing the span for both divs that use span by doing

```
.first {
        grid-column: span 1;
    }

.motor {
        grid-column: span 1;
    }
```

under @media.

Using block in media doesn't seem to work either. I'm really stumped on this. I'm brand new to coding so please be easy on me.

Comment: Welcome! First, there's a typo, since it's not `max-width =` it's `max-width: 768px`, second, there is no reason to use `grid` if you want one column, simply do `@media (min-width: 768px) {  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
} }` The idea here is start with mobile, **then** go to tablet/desktop. So, put that code where your original media query is. You also don't need to set `.grid-container` to display block before the media query, since `div` is already block.

Comment: Wow thank you, I swear I looked at that typo a thousand times too. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm voting to close this as a typo issue. Good luck! Also, move your `<ol>` out of your `<p>`